# Parse PE File with C in Windows

Tags: c, windows, import, hook, portable-executable

I've just started programming in C, so I'm not a pro at all, so please excuse my (probably) not so good code, but I'm struggling to find the cause of this problem. The output of this code in VS studio code is currently:

> Handle Process: 00000000000000c4 
> Imagebase:00007ff658520000

For some reason in Visual Studio only the Handle and not the imagebase is displayed, but in VS studio code both values are present.. but never mind.

When I load the PE file in x64 dbg and look at the imagebase in memory, it corresponds with this imagebase (it doesn't match with the imagebase on disk, but that's because ASLR has been applied), so far so good.
However, I try to localise the IAT, but for some reason it doesn't seem to work(and it doesn't work with notepad.exe either, maybe because of permissions?).

I'm referring to this part

```
if (dosHeaders->e_magic == IMAGE_DOS_SIGNATURE) {
printf("%s", dosHeaders->e_magic);}printf("error");}
```

I have tried many variations (like == NULL etc.), also with the NtHeaders, but it does not provide me anything, neither e_magic nor the string "error"). I don't get an error message but it keeps outputting only the handle to the process and the imagebase. Can someone explain why this is the case?

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <winternl.h>
#include <psapi.h>
#include <string.h>

int i;
typedef int(WINAPI* Func_Pointer)(HWND, LPCTSTR, LPCTSTR, UINT);
HMODULE array_modules[1024];
DWORD number_bytes;
TCHAR BUFFER[1024];

int main() {
    HANDLE Handle_Process = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, 11596);
    if (Handle_Process == NULL) {
        DWORD error = GetLastError();
        printf("Handle not retrieved %s", error);
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        printf("Handle Process: %p", Handle_Process);
        if (EnumProcessModules(Handle_Process, array_modules, sizeof(array_modules), &number_bytes) == 0) {
            printf("\n%s", "No Modules");
        }
        else {

            for (i = 0; i < (number_bytes / sizeof(HMODULE)); i++) {
                DWORD Module_LEN_string = GetModuleFileNameEx(Handle_Process, array_modules[i], BUFFER, 1024);
                // printf("%s\n", BUFFER);
                void* ImageBase = NULL;
                if (strstr(BUFFER, "OneDrive.exe") != NULL) {

                    ImageBase = array_modules[i];
                    printf("\n""Imagebase:""%p", ImageBase);
                    PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER dosHeaders = (PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER)ImageBase;
                    if (dosHeaders->e_magic == IMAGE_DOS_SIGNATURE) {
                        printf("%s", dosHeaders->e_magic);
                    }
                    printf("error");
                    PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS ntHeaders = (PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS)((DWORD_PTR)ImageBase + dosHeaders->e_lfanew);
                    //PIMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR ImportsDirectory = NULL;
                    IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY ImportsDirectory = ntHeaders->OptionalHeader.DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_IMPORT];
                    if (ntHeaders != NULL) {
                        printf("%08X", ntHeaders->Signature);
                    }
                    else { printf("NT Header not found"); }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Now would be a good time to step through the code in a debugger and see what is actually happening. Examine the data you're using for conditions to see if it matches what you think it should. Add a `\n` to the end of your `printf` format strings to help flush the output buffer.

Comment: Is `GetModuleFileNameEx` calling the ANSI or Unicode version of the function? If it is Unicode then `strstr(BUFFER, "OneDrive.exe")` will never be true. Using the explicit A or W versions of functions and char or wchar_t to match eliminates ambiguity.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Thank you. Now I tried a debugger and I got a segmentation error on this line: printf("%s", dosHeaders->e_magic). I just modified the code (to perform a NULL check) and now I do get the printf output "error".  It seems to be a memory protected area. I should have enough permissions to the target address space, also because I'm able to retrieve the ImageBase. When I alter the code and run it; the Segmentation error is at the line: PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS ntHeaders = (PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS)((DWORD_PTR)ImageBase+dosHeaders->e_lfanew). But here I'm not changing anything, only retrieving data.

Comment: Those pointers are valid only in the other processes address space. You'll need `ReadProcessMemory` to copy the data somewhere you can access from your process.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Thanks again, that makes sense but at the same I'm a little worried. Because if I need to copy the data to a buffer via ReadProcessMemory, I can extract useful data about for example IAT, so that's good. But I cannot change IAT entries in the target address space. So am I more or less obliged to use DLL injection, so inject a DLL in the target address space and change the IAT from there (if possible)?